# Difference between toString and serialize in Java

Tags: java, json, jaxb

I used Jersey to create a JAR-RS Web Service that responds with JSON formatted data.

When a request arrives, with the `@Path` annotation, a method captures the request processes it and return something.

For example, I created a `JSONArray` object called `jsonArray` in the method that handles the request. I can use `return jsonArray.toString();` to get a String and send it back. I can also use `return jsonArray` and JAXB(the annoation `@XmlRootElement` in the JSONArray class and `@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})` in the method) to automatically  serialize the object in JSON format.

I would like to know what is the difference between manually sending back a String and automatic serialization by using annotations.(Performance?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no output difference. The main difference is that `return jsonArray` can be considered to be more readable (especially for other programmers), while `return jsonArray.toString()` is more explicit. The problem with the former is that things are more obscure as someone reading your code needs to understand that something that gets the `jsonArray` object silently serializes it.

Another difference between approaches is that letting the framework do it guarantees that eventual updates in the framework will be reflected in the way things get serialized. The `toString()` method was not originally designed to provide a serialized view of an object, which can later be used to get the object back, but to simply provide a textual (even incomplete) representation of the object.

If the class you are using does not provide serialization or if the provided serialization does not generate JSON (or whatever format you want) correctly, you can always create your own serialization. Wrap the object inside of one belonging to a class that you defined and make such a class serializable. Then provide the following methods:

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException;
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;

And, yes, they should be private. See more here: [Discover the secrets of the Java Serialization API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javaserial-1536170.html)

Comment: On the other hand, the `toString()` implementation is always subject to change (unless its format is guaranteed by the Javadoc of the class, which it normally shouldn't be).

Comment: Good point. Explicit coding in this case is not as safe. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I use the JSONArray implementation of the site json.org but it seems that this implementation doesn't implements the serializable interface. So I cannot use JAXB... How can I do it with JAXB?

Comment: You can still do it if you provide your own way to serialize objects. I will update my answer.